# javascript reformat number with commas inside my function

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I have a super simple function that I just want to use to add multiple numbers to and have that number display as text on my page. The only function I'm missing is the comma separated format. I'm sure this is really easy, but I still can't seem to get it to work. Below is my code.

```
    function winnersTotal() {
    var jackpotTotal = 1510258 /*Jan & Feb Totals*/;
    jackpotTotal.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    document.getElementById("jackpotTotal").innerHTML = "$" + jackpotTotal;
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't show any attempt to display your currency in a comma separated format

Comment: I added the line I was experimenting with into the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```js
function winnersTotal() {
    var jackpotTotal = 1510258 /*Jan & Feb Totals*/;
    var withCommas = jackpotTotal.toLocaleString();
    document.getElementById("jackpotTotal").innerHTML = "$" + withCommas;
}
```

```html
<div id="jackpotTotal"></div>
<button onclick="winnersTotal()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Worked like a champ. I knew it was probably something simple I was missing, but I guess I was just hitting that wall! Thanks again!